# How to play any specific 'take' of the FBX animation in Blender using python script?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to play an animation from a fbx file. I want to choose between default or other 'take' of the animation. How can I do the same?

Comment: Even on the blender GUI while hovering over the "take" option on the right side menu ( under scene ), I cant see any api name. Please suggest.

Comment: If possible, please provide a test fbx to play with...